# Is an “s” at the end of a pluralized family name pronounced?

Tags: prononciation, pluriel, noms-propres, noms-de-famille

If it's a reference to the family, *Les Beauxhommes*, do you still not pronounce the *-s*?

Answer (score 12):

Unless it's spelled *Beauxhommès*, I would intuitively not pronounce the final *-s*. However, note that there's no pronunciation rule for last names.

Also, unlike English, if the original name doesn't have a final *-s*, putting one when referring to the family is not correct. The family of *Dominique Dupont* is *Les Dupont*, not *Les Duponts*, whereas *Homer Simpson*'s family is referred to as *The Simpsons*.

Comment: if it's spelled Beauxhommès I would avoid pronouncing it

Comment: @Mathieu Why would you?

Comment: I believe what @Mathieu means is that even in Beauxhommès you would pronounce the è but not the s, as in words like 'très'. That is, one would say /bozɔmɛ/ rather than /bozɔ'mɛs/ or /bo'zɔm/. But Beauxhommes would certainly be /bo'zɔm/.

Comment: @shva This would apply to common nouns, but not to family names. For example, you clearly pronounce the -s in [Denis Podalydès](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denis_Podalyd%C3%A8s) or [Yann Barthès](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yann_Barth%C3%A8s)

Answer (score 0):

In French, you can't add an "s" to proper nouns when you use the plural. In English, talking about a whole family you would say "*The Fords*", but in French you say "*Les Ford*".

Comment: You are 7 years late...

Comment: Better late than never! :)

Comment: @Ouch42 Yes, but that piece of information was already given, not to mention it doesn't apply to Beauxhommes which has an ending *S* whatever the case.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't serions.